# How to get Extended Security Maintenance for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, esm

I am not ready to move on from Ubuntu 16.04 quite yet, However I want to keep my OS secure.

How do I activate Extended Security Maintenance, (ESM)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Setup Ubuntu 16.04 ESM

I tried out ESM on Ubuntu 14.04, (16.04 activation should be the same).
It was pretty easy to set up.

I started out by installing an Ubuntu 14.04.4 ISO I had in my downloads folder. (I probably should have downloaded ubuntu-14.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso from https://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/). Latest release of 16.04 is 16.04.7 LTS available from https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/. At this point we at least know for a fact that the downloading of 14.04 and 16.04 Desktop and Server is fully supported by Canonical.

During the install process I selected the option to `download updates while installing`. I think that if I would have used point release 6, there might have been fewer updates and the process might have gone faster.

It was a pleasure to log into 14.04 after so long, sort of nostalgic.

First priority was security. For 14.04 and now 16.04, this means signing up for **Ubuntu Advantage (UA) client** and installing **ESM**.

The Ubuntu discourse page for information on installing Ubuntu ESM is https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-advantage-client/21788. the page directed me to https://ubuntu.com/advantage where I completed the registration process and ended up with a **free token**.

Back on https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-advantage-client/21788 I continued with **Installing the UA client** by running a couple of commands as instructed. Next I proceeded to **Attach the UA client**. I ran the line I got when registering `sudo ua attach [UNIQUECODE]`, (Please use your own free token).

Running `sudo ua status` I confirmed that ESM was enabled.

I completed the upgrade by running `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`. The installer ran for quite a while.

I ran Software Updater and It installed quite a few security updates.
All Settings/Overview tells me **System Up-To-Date**.

It appears to me that  Canonical is truly continuing support of Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 for free. I understand that Ask Ubuntu will not be allowind questions about ESM versions of Ubuntu?

**AND EVERYTHING WAS FREE**

Comment: Plus it's good for three years: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301683/ubuntu-16-04-support-past-2021-into-2024

Comment: This is good news for me! :-D

Answer (score 2):

In-case you get the **401 Unauthorized error** (like I did) after following all instructions correctly... This error appeared when trying to download any packages from esm through cli or software updater.

I restarted (no effect)

`sudo ua detach`

https://login.ubuntu.com/

Service Auth screen, yes log me in.
I then reattached with code from Ubuntu site, started working now.