# I was installing ubuntu 16.04 from a bootable usb alongside Windows 10 and everything went well except that I forgot to remove my usb when restarting

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, usb

So I followed all the steps correctly except that when I finished installing Ubuntu, I forgot to remove the usb before restarting.

And now that I've restarted, every time I boot ubuntu, it asks me to install it again, and so I did, but now the cycle goes on.

What should I do now? remove ubuntu from my partrition?

Comment: Why would you install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which reaches it's EOL for *standard* support in a few days and thus will be off-topic here?  Why not install a supported release that has life left, or do you intend switching to ESM/paid support? https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/  FYI: the 16.04 means 2016-April release, add 5 years and 2021-April is EOL of *standard* (free) support.

Comment: If you remove the thumb-drive, your installation should boot normally...

Comment: Because my university told me to do so, to be able to run a software named ROS, though I'm sure it runs on newer versions.

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ros-kinetic-end-of-life/21952  Your issues seems to be you haven't removed the thumb-drive thus you're booting into the *live* session (the installer) each time.. ie. user error and not a system error.  (You should be as specific as possible so we fully understand your issue, we currently don't know if you're talking about a Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS base, a Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS base.. etc.. or if you selected the thumb-drive in error as the boot device (thus making it needed to boot & that's your issue.. it's unclear & reads like user-issue/error)

Comment: If you have problems using ROS on later versions of Ubuntu, I have written up the procedure that can be used to Install ESM on 14.04 and 16.04 for free. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331483/how-to-get-extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04 ESM keeps the security up to date on some older versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the USB installer before rebooting. Instead of booting to the new install, you are booting to the Live USB each time you reboot.

Physically unplugging your USB device while the device is powered off should do the trick.