# Downloading Linux Ubuntu iso's

Tags: iso

can i download ubuntu 32 bits iso and where?
I wanted to run it on a VM so i can have multiple systems.
I also will need minimum Linux Ubuntu requierements.
I use VirtualBox via VDI.

Comment: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/   The minimum requirements however is more difficult, as they are kept in a single document which is amended as required (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).  Yes some releases may have provided specific requirements but they are release only (so you can look them up yourself once you've decided what you're after).  Current desktop requirements in link I provided were last changed for 17.10 or the return to GNOME desktop; but you can view the history yourself if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

From 18.04 up, Ubuntu has only 64-bit version. And 18.04 is the lowest release still supported. So if you need a 32-bit version, you need to use some old unsupported release (like 16.04 from the other answer - that's probably the best you can get).

Some other Ubuntu flavors, like [Lubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/) or [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/download/), still offer 32-bit version for 18.04 release. However, from 20.04 up, I don't know of 32-bit version of any flavor of Ubuntu.

Comment: Most other Ubuntu flavors, including Lubuntu and Xubuntu are supported for only 3 years. Their 18.04 support window just ended.

Comment: @raj: Ubuntu 16.04 is still supported by Canonical through Extended Security Maintenance, (ESM). It is just not supported by Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

found ASAP : https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386.iso <- oficial but old. as i know - unsupported.
requirements: 384MiB of RAM - everything i know cause can0nical doesn't want to share all list :'D

Comment: Thats really good, let me hop on into it!

Comment: okay - it's official so should work =]

Comment: -1: 16.04 is no longer supported, so it seems an unwise referral. If the OP encounters problems, we won't answer questions about it anymore. 18.04, which is supported for two more years, might be a more appropriate choice. So might Debian, which has current 32-bit packages.

Comment: -2 As above. Do NOT use EoL releases.

Comment: @olsQ **Canonical still supports Ubuntu 16.04** via Extended Security Maintenance, (ESM), see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331483/how-to-get-extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04. If you decide to use 16.04 you should activate ESM, it is Free. However Ask Ubuntu has stopped support for 16.04. You will have to go somewhere else if you have a question about it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Ubuntu 16.04 is "End of Standard Support" not "End of Life" by Ask Ubuntu definition.