# How to make a bootable USB drive on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, usb

How can I make my pen drive a bootable device?
Currently I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Previously I tried on Windows OS using third party software.

Comment: You may find the [official instructions helpful](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview).

Comment: The 16.04 support until 2024 is only Extended Security Maintenance, see: (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331483/how-to-get-extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04). Better to Start with 20.04. There are many ways to make a bootable USB. See my answer below. The little `?` in the upper right hand corner offers advice for Ask Ubuntu new users.

Comment: Thanks c.s. Cameron. Since my laptop's ram is only 2gb ram unable to run latest Ubuntu 20.04 version.

Comment: The Ubuntu flavours Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu have smaller footprints than standard Ubuntu; you can use those flavours of 20.04.x LTS in weaker computers (in your case with 2 GB RAM).

Comment: @sudodus - For my work I need chromium browser, microsoft teams installed, two notepad. All above to be kept opened and to be used them by pressing Alt+tab frequently . Will Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu mate work good? And screenshot need to be taken and saved frequently

Comment: I **think** those light-weight versions can do what you want, but you had better **test it yourself** before deciding which flavour to use for a long time. It might be easiest to test everything with a persistent live system in a fast USB pendrive (size at least 16 GB) before you decide what to install into your internal drive.

Answer (score 4):

### Persistent Install vs Full install

Ubuntu can be installed to a USB in different ways. A Live install does not save between sessions. A Persistent install extracts the OS from a compressed file and saves data to an overlay file or partition each session, and a Full install installs the complete OS to the USB just like an install to internal disk.

**Comparison between Persistent and Full install USB**

**Advantages of a persistent install:**

1. You can use the persistent pendrive to install Ubuntu to another computer.
2. A persistent install takes up less space on the pendrive.
3. You can reset the pendrive by overwriting the old casper-rw file with a new one.
4. The install to pendrive takes less time.
5. Slightly less wear on the drive.

**Advantages of a Full install:**

1. You can update and upgrade.
2. If you have problems or wish to modify, the solution is the same as with an internal install, (You can ask for help in the forums).
3. No ugly startup / install screen.
4. Better security, you can use full encryption
5. You can use proprietary drivers.
6. Swapfiles and partitions work and Hibernation can be enabled.
7. Many persistent installs are limited to a 4GB casper-rw and a 4GB home-rw persistence file, to get more persistence requires persistence partitions. Once casper-rw is full, the drive will not boot.
8. More efficient usage of disk space. Does not require reserved space for persistence.
9. Faster boot, **no automatic disk checking** or Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu screen.
10. You can run VBox and use virtual machines.
11. Generally faster boot than Live or Persistent USB's.
12. More stable, better for day to day use. I have run Ubuntu off a flash drive for 5 years making only LTS upgrades.

Note that once booted, both methods run at about the same speed. If the computer has lots of RAM Ubuntu should run mainly in RAM and there will not be a big difference between running off internal HDD and USB3 flash drive f.

**Full Install Method**

A quick and easy method to flash a Full install to USB can be found here: [Easy Full Install USB that Boots both BIOS and UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi)

A more traditional methods for creating a Full install USB from scratch can be found here: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-st)

Comment: When one wants to make a bootable pendrive, they may want to use it just as a temporarily installation media (the simplest method). It may be a good idea to add a link for that too.

Comment: @sivasdpi Follow sudodus' advice for a Live or persistent install. user68186's link is also good but I think you need access to a Ubuntu computer to follow it.

Answer (score 3):

### Ubuntu live (live-only) in a USB pendrive

All current Ubuntu versions (for example 20.04.x LTS) and flavours (for example standard Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu) are distributed with hybrid iso files.

This means that you can easily create a bootable live (live-only) pendrive: **clone from the iso file to the pendrive**. This is a one-to-one copy where every byte of the iso file is copied directly to the pendrive. **Such a drive is good for testing and installing Ubuntu into an internal drive.**

The Ubuntu flavours **Lubuntu**, **Ubuntu MATE** and **Xubuntu** have smaller footprints; you can use them in weaker computers (for example less RAM).

- You can find [links to download Ubuntu and the Ubuntu flavours here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/)
- There are instructions

  - [how to create a live drive](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) in Windows (DD-mode in Rufus is cloning)
  - [how to create a live drive](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview) in Ubuntu
- [More tips and links can be found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)
- and there: [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot/)

### Advanced ways to run Ubuntu from a USB pendrive

The answer by C.S.Cameron contains interesting arguments about something more advanced (than a live-only drive), and links to good descriptions of how to create an installed system in a USB pendrive:

- a persistent live system
- an installed system (like into an internal drive, but into a USB pendrive)

and he is recommending an installed system. I agree with many of his arguments, but I think that a persistent live system can also be quite useful, and it can be created from standard Ubuntu or an Ubuntu flavour with

- [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) in Windows (works with Ubuntu 20.04.x LTS according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10))
- [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in Ubuntu (mkusb version 12 (mkusb-dus) works with all current Ubuntu versions)

Comment: Hope you had a nice holiday, welcome back.